# Not able to start a chaincode in the test-network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I got stuck with the first tutorial for the test-network. I can set up a network and a channel with the network.sh-script, checked it with ‘docker ps -a’.

But trying to start the chaincode with

```
./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go
```

fails. The console-output complains about inconsistent vendoring and suggests ignoring the vendoring directory:

[console output with GOFLAGS='-mod=readonly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKE12.png)

If I export ‘-mod=readonly’ before deploying the chaincode the error stays the same, exporting ‘-mod=mod’ produces an error about a failed normalization of the chaincode path:

[console output with GOFLAGS='mod=mod'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpnN8.png)

I’m using linux-mint 20.2 (Uma), the prerequisites are of the following versions:

- git          2.25.1
- curl         7.68.0
- docker           20.10.14
- docker-compose   1.25.0  (build unknown)
- go           1.13.8
- jq           1.6

Setting up the network I once had the monitordocker-skript from the second tutorial running and noticed that it shows a different go-version (1.17.5 but still above the needed 1.13.x). And printing the version of docker-compose in the terminal there are the words “build unknown” behind the version-number, don’t know if that is useful.
Does anyone know why I’m not able to start a chaincode with the test-network?

---

Tried it with go 1.18, but there's no change.

Comment: I would recommend using go 1.17 or go 1.18 as when you deploy go chaincode via .network.sh deployCC it uses to golang tools to vendor the dependent code before packaging and sending it to the peers. The samples are written to use go modules and using go.1.13 module support isn't on by default also go 1.13 is pretty old and not supported by fabric or the golang team either anymore